# How can I add a self-written app in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site. I used a social media theme and have set-up the 'social media' part. I was hoping to add an app (apologies in advance if app is not the right word for it) that provides users daily challenges. Then when users get certain amount of points or achievements, they would be posted in the social media feed. I am learning as I go and I stared writing the app using JavaScript, html and CSS. Then I realized I have no clue how to actually add this "app" to my existing WordPress "social-media". Can anyone please help? I did some research and I thought maybe I can write the app as a plugin. But as far as I know, plugins are written in php? Can I combine it php with js, css and html to make this app? Or maybe put it in the "codeblock" element of theme editors?
Please help! Any suggestions? I would GREATLY appreciate any help!!!

Thanks!

Comment: You’ll need to create a WordPress plugin, so you’ll have to have a good grasp of PHP, possibly MySQL, along with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It’s not called an “app” in the WordPress ecosystem. What your attempting is too broad to cover in a single Stack Overflow question though.

Comment: hmm. thanks for the answer. If I can do this as plugin, I am going to give it a shot. I am sure it will be a good learning experience for me. Thanks again for your reply. Appreciate it!!

Comment: It's a big project, but a great way to learn. There's tons of WordPress tutorials and documentation around for you to refer to as well. Give it a shot, and if you run into problems, post focused questions back on Stack Overflow, and someone will undoubtably be able to help you. Good luck! :)